# Service PHP failed build Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to build docker and I have this error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (oniguruma) were not met:

No package 'oniguruma' found

Consider adjusting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ONIG_CFLAGS
and ONIG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring zip gd intl' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Better to share your Dockerfile

Comment: you can see it in bottom

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `libonig-dev` to your system dependencies, ie `apt-get install libonig-dev`